# Typescript: Accessing properties of an object from an inner function

Tags: typescript

I have this kind of object:

```
let obj = {
    ids: [],
    add: (newIds: [] => {
        this.ids.push(...newIds)
    })
}
```

Then, I want add some numbers to the ids array by calling `obj.add([1, 2, 3])`.
However, when I do that, I see that `this` becomes `undefined`.
Any idea how to solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Few things to notice.
`add` is an arrow function. `Arrow function` does not have own `this`. This is why TS gives you a hint.

Since you did not declare type of `isd` property, TS is unable to figure out the type of `ids: []`. Hence `ids` is infered as `never[]`.

You can use `type assertion` to assure typescript that empty array is actually an array of numbers and convert arrow function property to regular method:

```js
let obj = {
    ids: [] as number[],
    add(newIds: number[]) {
        this.ids.push(...newIds)
    }
}
```

Since, you are going into OOP, you can create a class instead of object:

```js
class Obj {
    ids: number[] = []
    add = (newIds: number[]) => {
        this.ids.push(...newIds)
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you @captain-yossarian. I kind of expecting inside `add()` I'd have the knowledge of the actual object, because I'm calling `add()` based on the object itself. Seems that is not the case.